# How to compile and run a C++ program with Eclipse for mac?

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation

I have a simple C++ app writen using the eclipse IDE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
printf("hello world");
return 0;
}
```

On mac does anybody know how to compile/run this code???

Comment: Have you read the C++ part of [the guide](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp)?

Comment: Do you have this code in a C++ project with an appropriate tool chain? If so, you should just have to push the hammer button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to open a terminal windows and go to the directory of your source file and type (assuming you have g++ installed):
`g++ filename.cpp`
To run it:
    `./a.out`

If you want the compiler to be integrated within eclipse, you can see this link on [how to build c/c++ projects in eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_c_build_over.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I have personally found that Eclipse can be a bit funky when it comes to C++. While Jaybears has already given a great answer, here are some alternatives you could consider for learning C++.

- The [C++ IDE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php) on [CodingGround](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm) is *super useful* for compiling simple programs. Its interface is really great for just focusing on the code and not getting bogged down in the complexity of a full-fledged IDE
- If you're looking for something that runs locally, QT Creator is used by several CS departments (such as Stanford's) for teaching C++ due to its' relative simplicity.